# What is meant by the term "consumable" with regards to object orientation?

Tags: oop

An interviewer used this term with me six months ago and I really didn't know what he meant.  I asked him to clarify and... he didn't.  I've searched the web off and on for a definition, and while I've seen it used in other questions or topics, I've never been able to find a clear, concise definition and example.  So, can someone please help me and shed some light on what "consumable" means?  Especially when used as in "One object is (or is not) consumable by another object."  I've made some inferences from context, but I don't really know how correct I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some additional context would be useful, but I suspect the relevant definition is something like *accepts as a parameter*.

In particular, when one speaks of a particular data format one can say that some program *produces* or *consumes* that format; this is just the generalization of that to object interfaces. Object (class) *A* is consumable by object *B* iff an A can be given a B and use it directly (as opposed to needing some kind of adapter).

Comment: Thanks to both users for attempting to provide an answer.  I wish I could provide more or better context, but all I really have was the way it was used in the interview and I included that in the question. As it is, Mr. Reid's answer gives me a good starting point to explore it more on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess he probably ask Type compatibility between one object to another and how one object can be passed (consumed) by others. Hard to answer though without the real context.